# Преобразовать KeyValue в ScanСode

Tags: c#

У события `PreviewKeyDownEventArgs` есть свойство `KeyValue`.

На примере нажатия клавиши `0` (ноль).

При нажатии клавиши ноль `KeyValue` выдает: **48**, `ScanCode` же должен содержать **11 (0x0B)**.

Как преобразовать `KeyValue` в `ScanCode`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тебе выдает Virtual Key code (x30 = 48):

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet=CharSet.Auto)]
internal static extern int  MapVirtualKey(int uCode, int uMapType);
```

Translates (maps) a virtual-key code into a scan code or character value, or translates a scan code into a virtual-key code.

Comment: Не вся документация по C# корректна к сожалению. В ней ни слова о Virtual Key, там в оригинале вот это: "The integer representation of the KeyCode property".  В KeyCode опять же ни слова о Virtual Key. Отправил предложение на правку в msdn.